# Laravel Yelp Api Object to Json

Tags: php, json, laravel, yelp

I am trying to get some data from the Yelp Api and Laravel 5.
This is my result. I have no idea how to convert it to a valid json format?

I am using this php client to consume the yelp api https://github.com/stevenmaguire/yelp-php

```
    {
    region: {
    span: {
    latitude_delta: 0.029259999999994,
    longitude_delta: 0.047640999999999
    },
    center: {
    latitude: 49.1328,
    longitude: 9.212475
    }
    },
    total: 113,
    businesses: [
    {
    is_claimed: false,
    rating: 3.5,
    mobile_url: "http://m.yelp.com/biz/vapiano-heilbronn?utm_campaign=yelp_api&utm_medium=api_v2_search&utm_source=80qGlvEI1gpPmfAxhHEKuQ",
    rating_img_url: "https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/5ef3eb3cb162/ico/stars/v1/stars_3_half.png",
    review_count: 33,
    name: "Vapiano",
    rating_img_url_small: "https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/2e909d5d3536/ico/stars/v1/stars_small_3_half.png",
    url: "http://www.yelp.com/biz/vapiano-heilbronn?utm_campaign=yelp_api&utm_medium=api_v2_search&utm_source=80qGlvEI1gpPmfAxhHEKuQ",
    categories: [
    [
    "Italian",
    "italian"
    ]
    ],
    phone: "+4971319199950",
    snippet_text: "Same same - not different. :) What do you expect from a Vapiano? That it tastes like a Vapiano! Here everything was fine, fresh and good. If you want a...",
    image_url: "https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/Cik80f2i1E_FfhIC7ZX9XQ/ms.jpg",
    snippet_image_url: "http://s3-media3.fl.yelpcdn.com/photo/HHcNqfQbtSeBmTEoKAujhA/ms.jpg",
    display_phone: "+49 7131 9199950",
    rating_img_url_large: "https://s3-media3.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/bd9b7a815d1b/ico/stars/v1/stars_large_3_half.png",
    id: "vapiano-heilbronn",
    is_closed: false,
    location: {
    city: "Heilbronn",
    display_address: [
    "Kaiserstr. 27",
    "74072 Heilbronn",
    "Germany"
    ],
    geo_accuracy: 8,
    postal_code: "74072",
    country_code: "DE",
    address: [
    "Kaiserstr. 27"
    ],
    coordinate: {
    latitude: 49.141868,
    longitude: 9.220792
    },
    state_code: "BW"
    }
    },
    {
    is_claimed: false,
    rating: 4.5,
    mobile_url: "http://m.yelp.com/biz/piccolo-mondo-heilbronn?utm_campaign=yelp_api&utm_medium=api_v2_search&utm_source=80qGlvEI1gpPmfAxhHEKuQ",
    rating_img_url: "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/99493c12711e/ico/stars/v1/stars_4_half.png",
    review_count: 12,
    name: "Piccolo Mondo",
    rating_img_url_small: "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/a5221e66bc70/ico/stars/v1/stars_small_4_half.png",
    url: "http://www.yelp.com/biz/piccolo-mondo-heilbronn?utm_campaign=yelp_api&utm_medium=api_v2_search&utm_source=80qGlvEI1gpPmfAxhHEKuQ",
    categories: [
    [
    "Italian",
    "italian"
    ]
    ],
    phone: "+497131251133",
    image_url: "https://s3-media3.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/knoT3BTaCnnx6jsO_KaN5Q/ms.jpg",
    location: {
    city: "Heilbronn",
    display_address: [
    "Hauptstr. 9",
    "74081 Heilbronn",
    "Germany"
    ],
    geo_accuracy: 9.5,
    postal_code: "74081",
    country_code: "DE",
    address: [
    "Hauptstr. 9"
    ],
    coordinate: {
    latitude: 49.1195,
    longitude: 9.19082
    },
    state_code: "BW"
    },
    display_phone: "+49 7131 251133",
    rating_img_url_large: "https://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/9f83790ff7f6/ico/stars/v1/stars_large_4_half.png",
    id: "piccolo-mondo-heilbronn",
    is_closed: false
    },
    {
    is_claimed: false,
    rating: 4.5,
    mobile_url: "http://m.yelp.com/biz/san-remo-heilbronn?utm_campaign=yelp_api&utm_medium=api_v2_search&utm_source=80qGlvEI1gpPmfAxhHEKuQ",
    rating_img_url: "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/99493c12711e/ico/stars/v1/stars_4_half.png",
    review_count: 16,
    name: "San Remo",
    rating_img_url_small: "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/a5221e66bc70/ico/stars/v1/stars_small_4_half.png",
    url: "http://www.yelp.com/biz/san-remo-heilbronn?utm_campaign=yelp_api&utm_medium=api_v2_search&utm_source=80qGlvEI1gpPmfAxhHEKuQ",
    categories: [
    [
    "Pizza",
    "pizza"
    ],
    [
    "Italian",
    "italian"
    ]
    ],
    phone: "+497131176519",
    image_url: "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/gI0n6APM2_lRnUWiIiSqxg/ms.jpg",
    location: {
    city: "Heilbronn",
    display_address: [
    "Weinsberger Str. 90",
    "74076 Heilbronn",
    "Germany"
    ],
    geo_accuracy: 9.5,
    postal_code: "74076",
    country_code: "DE",
    address: [
    "Weinsberger Str. 90"
    ],
    coordinate: {
    latitude: 49.1461,
    longitude: 9.23413
    },
    state_code: "BW"
    },
    display_phone: "+49 7131 176519",
    rating_img_url_large: "https://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/9f83790ff7f6/ico/stars/v1/stars_large_4_half.png",
    id: "san-remo-heilbronn",
    is_closed: false
    }
    ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the response json in a variable say

```
$result = <your json value>
```

and in your controller:

```
return response()->json(compact('result'));
```

your response will be this,

```
{
   result: {
        <your yelp data>
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. How can I access the properties. I try to pass this to my view. As there are no quotation marks around the key, I can't access the properties :(